# Using expressions as column names in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using dynamic column names in ggplot2, but with some names being expressions. How do I get ggplot2 to use expressions as column names in this case? An example follows below.

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(c(1,34,3,41,27,4,5,22), c(3,8,7,26,10,20,1,2))
names(data) <- c("name1", "name2")
rndidx <- sample(2)
ggplot(data, aes_string(names(data)[rndidx[1]])) + geom_line(aes_string(y=names(data)[rndidx[2]])) #This works fine
names(data) <- c("name1", "log(1+name2)")
ggplot(data, aes_string(names(data)[rndidx[1]])) + geom_line(aes_string(y=names(data)[rndidx[2]]))
#Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'name2' not found
```

Edit: The reason why I cannot simply use column names which are easier to handle is because the function which plots the data (i.e. there is a plotting function containing some calls to ggplot) receives heterogeneous data where column names vary from time to time and are sometimes expressions and sometimes not. I do not want the resulting plot to distort the column names in the labels or anywhere else where I might want to use them in the plot.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: If you just want to change the axis label, use `ylab`.

Comment: @Roland Please see the updated description. I want to be able to plot arbitrary things with ggplot2 without distorting the original column names. I do not have much control over the column names unfortunately. The axis labels are just examples of what I need to have intact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it, but it would be easier to rename the variables beforehand.  Anyway, here is one way,

```
ggplot(data, aes_string(gsub("\"", "`", deparse(names(data)[rndidx[1]])))) +
  geom_line(aes_string(y=gsub("\"", "`", deparse(names(data)[rndidx[2]]))))
```

You basically just need to find a way to get around the `parse(text=` that happens when `aes_string` evaluates.

Comment: In my case it is not easier to rename the variables beforehand unfortunately since I really need the original variable names. The program is quite complex and I have many different column names which I can not control easily, and they are different each time. Your solution worked perfectly however, thanks!

Comment: great! I just reran it and realized that you had a random index in there, so The same would need to be done for the first `aes_string` variable as well.